# How to join tables in Hive using find_in_set

Tags: hadoop, join, hive, find-in-set

Table A contains a column `id(string)`
Table B contains a column `ids(string)`,like `"id1,id2,id3"`

to join A and B, I want A.id can be found in B.ids:

```
select count(1) from 
(select id from A) as t1
join
(select ids from B) as t2
on find_in_set(t1.id, t2.ids) != 0;
```

then I see :

> [Error 10017]: Line 1:91 Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN '0'

if I change `!=` to `=`, the error is still the same.

How to solve this problem?